# Calculating the number of duplicate rows in a column of Excel by Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel document and I want to implements 2 things.

1. I want to get the number of violations in each category
2. The earliest and latest violation date for each category

I can already get the document via `Apache Poi` but I could not achieve these.

The code that I am getting the `xlsx` file is like below:

```
public class App {
    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "./data.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

        // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
        System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");



        Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
        System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
        while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
            Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
            System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
        }


        // Getting the Sheet at index zero
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();


        System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // Closing the workbook
        workbook.close();
    }


}
```

My excel file is like below:
[image: Excel file]

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to skip the first row since it seems to be a 'header row' without real data
2. Since you're interested in the number of violations and the dates (earliest and latest) by category only columns C and D (or E - kind of hard to see in your excel sheet screenshot) need to be evaluated.

So assuming the relevant date is in column D (and therefore has index 3) and the column is a date column, you can use something like this:

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
boolean isFirstRow = true;
Map<String, AtomicInteger> numbersByCategory = new TreeMap<>();
Map<String, Date> earliestDateByCategory = new TreeMap<>();
Map<String, Date> latestDateByCategory = new TreeMap<>();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    if (isFirstRow) {
        isFirstRow = false; //skip the header row
        continue;
    }

    //first find out if it's the first row to this category; if not increment the number by one
    String category = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
    AtomicInteger numberToCategory = numbersByCategory.get(category);
    if (numberToCategory == null) {
        numberToCategory = new AtomicInteger(0);
        numbersByCategory.put(category, numberToCategory);
    }
    numberToCategory.incrementAndGet();

    Date relevantDateOfRow = row.getCell(3).getDateCellValue();

    //now check if the date is a new 'earliest' to the category 
    Date earliestDateToCategory = earliestDateByCategory.get(category);
    if (earliestDateToCategory == null || relevantDateOfRow.before(earliestDateToCategory)) {
        earliestDateByCategory.put(category, relevantDateOfRow); //we found a new earliest date
    }

    //now check if the date is a new 'latest' to the category
    Date latestDateToCategory = latestDateByCategory.get(category);
    if (latestDateToCategory == null || relevantDateOfRow.after(latestDateToCategory)) {
        latestDateByCategory.put(category, relevantDateOfRow); //we found a new latest date
    }
}

//now you have 3 results that can be used for further processing (e.g. show on screen)
System.out.println("Number: " + numbersByCategory);
System.out.println("Earliest: " + earliestDateByCategory);
System.out.println("Latest: " + latestDateByCategory);
```